# window onerror filter out the addon/extension errors

Tags: javascript, onerror

I use a simple custom code to catch my js errors from my website. I use a window.onerror handler. However, I see that there are many addon/extension errors that users have installed into their browsers. I don't want to get those. Is there a way to filter those out and get only what is related to my code?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this would work, but as mdn, there is a property in the [ErrorEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ErrorEvent), the [ErrorEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ErrorEvent) is defined in here :

```js
addEventListener("error",function(err){
console.log(err) //Here it is your error, ErrorEvent
})
```

Now, when you know the name of the javascript file, you can use the file, so you can filter the errors by file names :

```js
err.filename
```

and if you are looking for chrome extensions, maybe it is near to impossible, as the chrome extensions are a part of the UI and therefore, a part of the window object

Answer (score 0):

From docs http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window.asp

The window object is supported by all browsers. It represents the browser's window.
All global JavaScript objects, functions, and variables automatically become members of the window object.
Global variables are properties of the window object.
Global functions are methods of the window object.
Even the document object (of the HTML DOM) is a property of the window object.

So that's why addons error appears in your catch block.

But from this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror

I would suggest you inside onError handler check messages and sources to see if this error corresponds to your code. If not just ignore it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[`e.stack`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/stack) includes URLs to the triggering script, so with that you can filter only for first-party scripts. Keep note that `e.stack` is non-standard, but widely supported.

```js
window.addEventListener('error', e => {
  if (e.error?.stack?.includes(window.location.origin)) {
    // handle first-party error
  }
});
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', e => {
  if (e.reason?.stack?.includes(window.location.origin)) {
    // handle first-party error
  }
});
```

Comment: That sounds correct, though I'm no specialist. I'm wondering if Chrome's extension would even throw in the main window given they're only in SW or in popup, so the issue might be moot there, except if OP wants to capture injected scripts, in which case the stack trick wouldn't work.

Comment: I found a better solution and updated the answer. Stack trace includes the URL to the script so you can filter with it and in my testing, this works in all browsers.

Comment: But then they'll lose the errors thrown from external scripts

Comment: 3rd-party scripts can be filtered via their origin as well, but I'll leave that as an exercise to the user.

Comment: You most certainly want to know when one of your libraries thrown. Often times it will be because you passed it something wrong, but it's not necessarily in the stack

Comment: My libraries are all first-party origin, so I guess if your libraries come from other origins, you should filter for those origins as well.

Comment: Some non-extension errors may have no error/stack (for example CORS errors when you do `fetch()`), so this solution may filter out more than you would want.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can filter out errors that are related to browser extensions or addons by checking the error object passed to the window.onerror handler. Browser extension errors often originate from content scripts injected into the webpage, and they usually have a specific structure that can help you distinguish them from errors caused by your own code.

Here's a basic example of how you can filter out errors caused by browser extensions/addons:

```
window.onerror = function(message, source, lineno, colno, error) {
    // Check if the error object exists and if it originates from a browser extension
    if (error && error.stack && error.stack.includes('chrome-extension://')) {
        // This error is likely caused by a browser extension, so ignore it
        return;
    }

    // Log or handle errors caused by your own code here
    console.error("Error:", message, "at", source, "line:", lineno, "column:", colno);
};
```

In this code:

We check if the error object exists and if it has a stack trace (which most errors thrown by JavaScript engines do).

We then check if the stack trace includes the string 'chrome-extension://', assuming Chrome as the browser, but you can adjust it according to other browsers if needed. This string usually appears in the stack trace for errors originating from browser extensions/addons.

If the error is detected to be from a browser extension, we simply return and do nothing.

If the error is not from a browser extension, you can handle it as needed.

Please note that this approach might not catch all errors from browser extensions/addons, as they might have different origins depending on the browser and how they are implemented. However, it should help filter out a significant portion of them.

Answer (score -3):

Just use event listeners like this:

```js
window.addEventListener('error', (e) => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Event handlers (like `window.onerror`) are only useful for ancient browsers.

Comment: The question is not about how to log errors, the question is about how to filter out rubbish errors coming from extensions while logging.